# ¿De que forma podria paginar con vuejs, axios y php puro?

Tags: mysql, vue.js, php7

```
public function paginarClasificados($pagina)
{
    #Inicializamos el tamaño de la pagina
    $tamaño_pagina = 5;
    #Iniciamos en donde iniciara la pagina
    $pagina = 1;
    $empezar_desde = ($pagina - 1) * $tamaño_pagina;
    #Inicializamos el array de datos que devolvera la paginación
    $datos = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tclasificados";
    $stmt1 = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($query);
    $stmt1->execute(array());
    $num_filas = $stmt1->rowCount();
    $total_paginas = (int) ceil($num_filas / $tamaño_pagina);


    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM tclasificados LIMIT $empezar_desde, $tamaño_pagina";
    $stmt2 = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($query2);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $datos = $stmt2->fetchAll();

    return $total_array = array(
        "datos" => $datos,
        "paginacion" => array(
            "num_reg" => $num_filas,
            "mostramos_reg" => $tamaño_pagina,
            "mostrando" => $pagina,
            "total_paginas" => $total_paginas
        )
    );


}
```

### quiero devolver estas variables al  igual que laravel

pagination: {
                    'total': 0,
                    'current_page': 0,
                    'per_page': 0,
                    'last_page': 0,
                    'from': 0,
                    'to': 0 
                },

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual seria la pregunta?